# How can I shorten the link to the photo I used in my SVG?

Tags: html, svg, href, xlink

The link to the photo in my svg is over 1,100 lines of code. I'm pretty sure its because I used the image trace tool in Adobe Illustrator, then I cut the exact portion I wanted out in Photoshop, then I created the SVG. If my only option is to recreate the logo more efficiently that's fine. I guess i'm just hoping there's an easier way since I already spent a few hours on it.

I keep searching for a way to optimize it and haven't found anything specific to this situation. Has anyone run into this before?

```
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="560" height="231" id="Layer_1_1_" 
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAi4AAADuCAYAAAAePYxCAAAACXBIWXMAABSbAAAUmwGHzxCEAAAA
GXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAABWT9JREFUeNrsvWmPJFl2JfZs8X33
2DPWjCUj11p6qapucro5I4kgZgiCGHAolhrQBwLzCwRhBG2j7YP0YT5QwAADQhI1gho1GpLAsLsF
LkOou9nd1d21dFVWVWYtmVWVlWtExubhsfhqZrrnvvfMzT08IjwiPLIiq+wlLH0Jd3OzZ8/ePe/c
e88VImxhC1vYwha2sIXtKWlG2AVh+6K0//af/w9WJBpJRGmLRWNWJpMx05lMwrKsJP3ZejJH4Ylm
0xGe5/X8jWazKRzHOfQzrtqnQ8891+Xf4PfpOb7fUM8bjYZwHXpsNppO09lpOM2a02i49NkmfW7H..." transform="matrix(0.5357 0 0 0.5504 6.5751 1.8521)">
</image>
```

Obviously I cant show all of the characters, but there's over just under 12,000, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you probably used filters and layer modifiers and therefore photoshop rasterized parts of the svg. could you post a link to the source file, so we could help you better?

Comment: I was able to get it figured out. I in ignorance took my svg and put it into ps to edit the brightness and then put it back. I just undid those changes and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the base64 source of an SVG image. Just use a .svg file.

You can use [this tool](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/svg) here to convert your base64 date back to an SVG file.

Then you can easily link that file like this:

```
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="560" height="231" id="Layer_1_1_" xlink:href="https://example.com/someimage.svg" transform="matrix(0.5357 0 0 0.5504 6.5751 1.8521)">
</image>
```